# virtual network interface for ShrewSoft VPN Client

Tags: networking, ipsec

I use ShrewSoft VPN Client 2.1.7 under Arch Linux (i686) to connect to the company network using IPSec. It is configured by a .vpn file. How can I make it create a virtual network interface?